# Problem with drupal_valid_path

Tags: path-aliases

In my custom module I'm using `drupal_valid_path` to check if a given alias exists before I create such.

```
$target_alias = 'some/path';
if(drupal_valid_path($target_alias, FALSE) === FALSE){
  // create 'some/path'
}
```

The function **always** returns FALSE and thus creates tons of identical aliases. What could be wrong?

I have tried various boolean expressions, such as: `!drupal_valid_path` or weak type test `==`. To no avail.

Comment: The function's description is _Checks a path exists and the current user has access to it._...does the user you're running this script as have access to the path?

Comment: AFAICT, yes. I'm logged in as an admin...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess the problem is that `drupal_valid_path()` is expecting a system path, and you're passing it an alias.

Fortunately there's a function to determine the system path from the alias, [`drupal_lookup_path()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_lookup_path/7). I would have thought a simple change to your code like this would make it work:

```
$target_path = drupal_lookup_path('some/path');
if(drupal_valid_path($target_path, FALSE) === FALSE){
  // create 'some/path'
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I think there's a problem with routers in my code, as uncommenting them made the function return TRUE, but just once. I think I'll delete the question until I have more detail. Thanks for suggestion though. Appreciated.

Comment: @Artur I don't see any reason for deleting the question (supposing you can): You asked a specific question, which was answered. This answer is correct for the question you asked; I would rather accept it, and ask a new question when you investigated more on what happens.